# Azure German Cloud - Notification Hub creation failed

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I got some errors in Germany Cloud with the Notification Hubs. If you want to create an new Hub to an existing namespace, you will get the error "Notification Hub already exists". You can use every Name you like always the same. If you create a Hub with an new namespace you will get "Internal Server Error".

Does somebody has any idea to fix it?

BR
Sven

Answer (score 0):

This issue may occur Adding special characters to the namespace name (underscores, slashes, square brackets, etc) causes an error to be displayed saying "Namespace already exists. Please enter a different name."

You may refer to the suggestion mentioned in the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051976/azure-notification-hub-namespace-error) thread

Answer (score 0):

The issue should now be fixed, it was due to a regression

Thanks,
Karl