# The specified name is not available Azure EventHub namespace

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-rm-template

I have tried to deploy an ARM template with new EventHub Namespace. But it is failing with the `BadRequest` error, `The specified name isn't available.`. But the name has not used previously in anything under that resource group. When I tried to create a similar resource manually from the portal it is working fine. So it should not be a privileges' issue. Can anyone suggest my issue here please?

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces",
    "apiVersion": "2021-11-01",
    "name": "xxxx-xxxx-xxx-000",
    "location": "[variables('location')]",
    "sku": {
        "name": "Standard",
        "tier": "Standard",
        "capacity": 1
    },
    "properties": {
        "isAutoInflateEnabled": false,
        "maximumThroughputUnits": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be related to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38301620/8742162) ?

Comment: We need to add globaly unique name @Avilon with correct required format. Please check  this [*MS DOC*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.eventhub/namespaces?tabs=json#property-values) once

Comment: Are you entering random numbers only ..!!

Comment: No I am entering a combination of letters for the part I put 'x' followed by '-000'. But It seems really doubtful if this name is used across azure. @AjayKumarGhose-MT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***We have tried the same in our environment to create an eventhub namespace with name similar to yours and it works fine .***

Below is the workaround we followed;

*In the same name that we will be trying to deploy through ARM  created in portal  and then trying to deploy through ARM and got the same issue.*

[image]

Y*es its a known issue we can expect , To ensure that we need to provide the name which is globally unique and not by any resource group ,Not only at your resource group ,this name should not use anywhere(Azure)* .

Make sure that if you have created it through portal and trying with ARM again , please delete the previous one if you are owner of that namespace. And try again with same name after deletion.

***We have provided the namespace just similar to you to check whether this value is passed or not and it works successfully***.

`template.json`

```
"resources": [
{
"type": "Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces",
"apiVersion": "2022-01-01-preview",
"name": "[parameters('namespaces_ajletter_test_111_something_name')]",
"location": "Central India",
"sku": {
"name": "Standard",
"tier": "Standard",
"capacity": 1
},
```

**OUTPUT SCREENSHOT FOR REFERENCE:-**

[image]
[image]

For more information please refer the below links:-

- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**| [***EventHub ARM EXCEPTION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/resource-manager-exceptions#error-code-badrequest) & [***Create EventHub Namespace using ARM Template***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-resource-manager-namespace-event-hub) .

Comment: You're right, Changing the name got it fixed. Thanks @AjayKumarGhose-MT